# How to style Android default ViewPager's bar, created from Android Studio template

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to create a tabbed activity, and I'm using `ViewPager` for that (actually, Android Studio created it from template, I didn't even know what ViewPager was). I want to style the tab-bar below (indicated with red "circle"):

[image]

I've tried setting `styles.xml` tried almost everything, but still, nothing applies to that. Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

Ironically, the generated code (by Android Studio's latest version) has many deprecated method calls, but I don't want to touch them unless I know what exactly I'm doing. Here is the layout file (`activity_main.xml`), again, generated by Android Studio:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="MY_APP_IDENTIFIER"/>
```

How can I change the colors of the tab bar?

Comment: You can achieve custom tab bar using some code from Google's open source  I/O Schedule app. Click [here](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html) to view a Tutorial that i have made on Sliding tabs with Material Design  :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using onPageSelected it's probably the simplest way I think. [Here](https://zeeprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/android-hide-toolbar-in-specified-fragment/) is a link.